# Binding energy in Euclidean Gravity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, potential-energy, classical-field-theory

I suppose I'm asking in the context of classical gravity, but an answer in the effective GR quantum theory would be fine too.
I can't seem to find much on the attractive nature of the gravitational field when one considers Euclidean gravity.

Is there a simple resource or exposition showing that Euclidean gravity is attractive for simple scalar matter?

or

Is Euclidean gravity attractive between scalar matter?

I have looked in Zee's nutshell QFT book, and in section 1.5 he works out the attractive nature of gravity in Minkowski signature.  I'm working on tracing all the signs back to their origin and starting in Euclidean and repeating the calculation, but it seems like an obvious question one would have asked decades ago, so I thought I would probe the community.

Thanks